# cant render because of appcompat

Tags: android

My android studio cant seem to render properly because of the com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01 though i'm not too sure

Here's the error message that displays

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0-rc01, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc01 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion)

Here's my gradle build(project)

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

and here's my gradle build(module)

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jbdelosreyes.finalmvp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: The error message should also tell you how to have gradle print the entire dependency tree. This will help you track down which library is using an older version of appcompat.

Answer (score 0):

Set your

```
compileSdkVersion to 27
targetSdkVersion to 27
```

And

```
appCompat version to 

27.1.1
```

Comment: now this shows up *Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1-rc01* and it says gradle project sync failed

Comment: @AnotherJuan Note that this answer says to use `27.1.1`, NOT `27.1.1-rc01`.

Comment: Remove -rc01 . It’s only 27.1.1

Comment: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).

Comment: now it says that. sorry if im causing too much trouble

Comment: Replace all 26.1.0 with 27.1.1

Comment: oh but it's rendering now. as long as it works. thanks man! thanks a lot really

Comment: i dont have anything else that is 26.1.0.. anyway it renders now so i think it's good enough. though its probably not a good programming practice lol

Comment: I’m glad ! You are free to ask questions, this is what stack overflow all about. You. Can accept this as correct answer if this solved your problem

Comment: It’s not like a programming practice, v21 is the latest stable version. 26 is older one so you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

## It's more a hack than Answer.

**TL;DR**

> This is happening because in support lib 28.0.0-rc01 there is a bug related to rending the Appcompat ActionBar with unknown error.

#### How to use design view until Android team fixes the bug?

1. Goto app -> `build.gradel` file
2. `compileSdkVersion 27` **27** not **28**
3. `targetSdkVersion 27` **27** not **28**
4. `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'` **27.1.1** not **28.0.0-rc01**

**P.S.:- This doesn't mean that downgrading is a good option or answer but for now it is!**

Answer (score 0):

try it 
in Your build :

```
   buildscript {

    repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
        dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application 
     dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
      }

       allprojects {
      repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }

    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    google()
    jcenter()
     }
     }

      task clean(type: Delete) {
      delete rootProject.buildDir
       }
```

in Gradle.Build :

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
   compileSdkVersion 25
   buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.naser.arabic"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
     buildTypes {
     release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 
        getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- 
        android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        }
        sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = 
        ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
        compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
         sourceCompatibility 1.8
       }
       }

      dependencies {
      compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 
      'libs')

           androidTestCompile('
            com.android.support.test.espresso:es 
           presso-core:2.2.2', {
              exclude group: 'com.android.support', 
        module: 
      'support-annotations'
         })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat- 
        v7:25.3.1'
        compile files('libs/universal-image-loader- 
        1.9.3.jar')
        compile 
         'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
        layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
         compile 'com.android.support:support- 
        v4:25.3.1'}
```